# Set a functions variables with an object's values

Tags: javascript

Normally I would set a functions variables with something like this:

```
var width = null;
var height = null;

if(options) {
    if(options.width) width = options.width;
    if(options.height) height = options.height;
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this with something like:

```
var width = null;
var height = null;

if(options) {
    for(var val in options) {
        val = options[val];
    }
}
```

In this simple example it doesn't seem like a big benefit, but in a situation where I have a multitude of variables to set with values from a single object (in such a way that say...ajax does it), it would be much easier to just loop the object and do it that way.

Comment: It is not possible to dynamically declare variables (like in a loop). Consider just using the `options` object to retrieve the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly. If you want to attach things to the global namespace (`window`), you could write something like this:

```
if (options) {
  for(var val in options) {
    window[val] = options[val];
  }
}
```

...but you would generally want to avoid cluttering up `window` unless absolutely necessary. A commonly used alternative would be to create an object for holding default options, and simply overwrite them as new options are provided:

```
var defaults = {
  height: 0,
  width: 0
}

if (options) {
  for(var val in options) {
    defaults[val] = options[val];
  }
}

// use values now stored in `defaults`
console.log(defaults.height);
```

Comment: I'd do this to fill the `defaults` object: `if ( options ) Object.keys( options ).forEach(function ( key ) { defaults[key] = options[key]; });` - this way you don't have to declare an additional variable.

Comment: Nice! `Object.keys()` might be an issue with browsers that don't support 1.8.5, though.

Comment: ES5-shim takes care of that `:)`